# Android Background Runnable not working on older devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice, android-intentservice

I have the following running at startup inside of an `IntentService`

```
threadManager.postBackgroundRunnableDelayed(() -> {
            try {
                // Calling getToken and getId must be on separate thread. Otherwise, it blocks UI thread.
                String token = instanceID.getToken(SENDER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
                String id = instanceID.getId();
                Timber.d("id: " + id);
                Timber.d("token: " + token);
                lazyRestQueue.get().sendGcmToken(new GcmPushRequest(id, token), getSendGcmTokenCallback());
                setupAnalytics(token);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "Exception during registration");
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                setHasToken(false);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // This will be thrown if Localytics was not properly setup
                Timber.e(e, "Exception during registration");
            }
        });
```

When I run it on anything below API 18 it causes the app to close (not crash oddly, just close)

can someone give me advice on this? I know it probably has to do with the service or something not timing properly

Comment: You might still be getting a crash, it's just squelched due to it occurring in a separate thread (your `onHandleIntent` function is already a background thread). I would either attach a debugger to see what is happening at that point of your app, or add a third catch clause for the `Exception` class, and print that out in logcat.

Comment: It isn't throwing any exception of any kind sadly. also if I delay the action itll work oddly

Comment: Try putting the block of code inside the `postBackgroundRunnableDelayed()` function on a regular service, and see if it still does the same thing.

Comment: I don't think runnable delayed is viable long term. don't want to just stall to solve the issue unless theres a really good reason for doing so.